# MPS Double values as Concect propterties

Tags: mps

Trying to add a double property to my Concept:

```
concept Location extends BaseConcept
....
  properties:
  longitude : double
  latitude : double
```

I know that properties is looking for PrimitiveDataTypeDeclaration, but I just find there integer, strings and boolean.

How can I add doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the _FPNumberString type to hold double values in properties